# TitledBorder in JPanel moves when translate() method is used

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, border

I have created a `JPanel` and add it on a `JFrame`. `JPanel` has `TitledBorder`, but when I use the method `translate()`, e.g.,

```
g2.translate(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
```

the whole component, including the border is translated. The effect is presented on Figure 1.
[image: Figure 1]

The desired result is depicted on the figure below.
[image: Figure 2]

Code is pasted below.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

class GPanel extends JPanel {
    private void doDrawing(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.translate(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        doDrawing(g);
    }
}

class Main extends JFrame {
    public Main() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main ex = new Main();
        ex.setSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        GPanel panel = new GPanel();
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Title"));
        ex.add(panel);
        ex.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        ex.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could this be caused from the layout manager being used on the JFrame? If you create a JPanel with the titled border to hold GPanel, does the error persist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have invoked `setBorder()` on an instance of `GPanel` and then modified the graphics context's transform in the latter's implementation of `paintComponent()`. The border doesn't know about this, so the result shown is entirely expected. Instead, follow the parent `JComponent` implementation advice for [`setBorder()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setBorder-javax.swing.border.Border-): "put the component in a `JPanel` and set the border on the `JPanel`." A related example is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43902419/230513).

In the variation below,

- The enclosing `bPanel` now has the `Border`, and the enclosed `gPanel` can safely manipulate the graphics context.
- Before `translate()`, the red dot is centered on the origin; after `translate()`, the blue dot is centered on the origin, but the origin has moved.
- Don't use `setPreferredSize()` when you really mean to override [`getPreferredSize()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513).
- Don't extend `JFrame` needlessly.

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

class GTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        GPanel gPanel = new GPanel();
        JPanel bPanel = new JPanel();
        bPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Title"));
        bPanel.add(gPanel);
        f.add(bPanel);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static class GPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final int N = 16;

        private void doDrawing(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.setPaint(Color.red);
            g.fillOval(-N, -N, 2 * N, 2 * N);
            g2.translate(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
            g2.setPaint(Color.blue);
            g.fillOval(-N, -N, 2 * N, 2 * N);
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            doDrawing(g);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(256, 256);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You might need to restore the move made by executing `g2.translate(x, y);` with `g2.translate(-x, -y);`:

```
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
double x = getWidth() / 2d;
double y = getHeight() / 2d;
g2.translate(x, y);
g2.setPaint(Color.BLUE);
g2.fill(s);
g2.translate(-x, -y);
```

Another common way is to use a new `Graphics` object which is a copy of GPanel's `Graphics` object:

- [Graphics#create()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#create--), [Graphics#dispose()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#dispose--)

```
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
g2.translate(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
g2.setPaint(Color.BLUE);
g2.fill(s);
g2.dispose();
```

**Main2.java**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class GPanel extends JPanel {
  private final Rectangle s = new Rectangle(0, 0, 16, 16);
  private void doDrawing(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillRect(s.x, s.y, s.width, s.height);

//     Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
//     double x = getWidth() / 2d;
//     double y = getHeight() / 2d;
//     g2.translate(x, y);
//     g2.setPaint(Color.BLUE);
//     g2.fill(s);
//     g2.translate(-x, -y);

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    g2.translate(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
    g2.setPaint(Color.BLUE);
    g2.fill(s);
    g2.dispose();
  }

  @Override
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    doDrawing(g);
  }
}

public class Main2 extends JFrame {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
      GPanel panel = new GPanel();
      panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Title"));
      JFrame ex = new JFrame();
      ex.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      ex.getContentPane().add(panel);
      ex.setSize(400, 400);
      ex.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      ex.setVisible(true);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
private void doDrawing(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.translate(0, 0);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but this code doesn't solve the problem. I need to translate origin into the `(width / 2, height /2)'