# Java SetIcon changing layout border of jLabel

Tags: java, image, swing

I'm trying to create a kind of zoom whit the mouse wheel. Everytime i move the wheel, teoricaly both the jlable and the image change sizes according(im showing the width value).

**Verifiable Example:**

```
   Whitout setIcon:                        Whit setIcon:
    Img:144                                  Img:144
    jLable:144                               jLable:144
    Img:160                                  Img:144
    jLable:160                               jLable:144
    Img:176                                  Img:160
    jLable:176                               jLable:160
    Img:192                                  Img:144
    jLable:192                               jLable:144
```

The problem happens when i try insert the image into the jframe:

```
jLabel1.setIcon(resizedImage);
```

Can anyone explain me this behavior? It seems for some reason setIcon uses the previous layout, instead of the correct one.

**Minimal Version of code:**

```
public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
            int delta = 16 * (int)e.getPreciseWheelRotation(); 
            Dimension factor = new Dimension(jLabel1.getWidth()+delta, jLabel1.getHeight()+delta);  

            jLabel1.setSize(factor);//force jlabel1 to get the new size

            //Relocate Image
            Image img = image.ScaleImage(factor);//Teoricaly give the image whit the new size
            ImageIcon resizedImage = new ImageIcon(img);                   

            //Gives the image to jlabel
            jLabel1.setIcon(resizedImage);
        }
});
```

**Complete Version of Code:**

```
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.Image;
    import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
    import java.awt.event.MouseWheelEvent;
    import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
    import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import pokemon.classes.BitmapController;
    import pokemon.objects.ResizableImage;
    import javax.swing.border.Border;



public class Aplicacao extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public Aplicacao() {
              initComponents();
            setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
            ///
            BitmapController file = new BitmapController();
            ResizableImage image = new ResizableImage(file.readImage());//reads the bmp image
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image.master);
            jLabel1.setIcon(icon);

            //Create the Controller for scroll effect
            scrollController(image);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Aplicacao().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    } 

    public void scrollController(ResizableImage image){
    Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE, 5);
        jLabel1.setBorder(border);
        jLabel1.addMouseWheelListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
                    int delta = 16 * (int)e.getPreciseWheelRotation(); 
                    Dimension factor = new Dimension(jLabel1.getWidth()+delta, jLabel1.getHeight()+delta);  
                    //jLabel1.setSize(factor);

                    //Relocate Image
                    //System.out.println("width: " + image.ScaleImage(factor).getWidth(rootPane));
                    Image img = image.ScaleImage(factor);
                    System.out.println("Img:"+img.getWidth(rootPane));
                    System.out.println("jLable:"+jLabel1.getWidth());
                    ImageIcon resizedImage = new ImageIcon(img);                   
                    jLabel1.setIcon(resizedImage);
                }
        });
    }

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(68, 68, 68)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 128, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(472, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(74, 74, 74)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 256, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(143, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>  

}

////Class ResizableImage 

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage; 

public class ResizableImage {
public BufferedImage master;
private Image scaled;


public ResizableImage(BufferedImage master){
    this.master=master;        
}

public Image ScaleImage(Dimension size){
    Image scaledImg = master.getScaledInstance(size.width, size.height,Image.SCALE_DEFAULT); 
    return scaledImg;
    }
}

//Class BitmapController
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class BitmapController {

    public BufferedImage readImage(){
        BufferedImage image = null;
        try{
            image = ImageIO.read(new File("D:/Tileset42.bmp"));
            //System.out.println("ola");
        }catch (Exception ex){ System.out.println("error");} 
        return image;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should just let the label calculate it's own size requirements based on the icon/text properties

Comment: I also created a border to the jframe behave better. When i just change the image size, the image gets bigger however the jframe stay whit the same size. In other words the image gets cut and since im using the jlabel size (check factor)  if the jlabel doenst grow in the new interation it will stay the same size. I took a look on the fill vs fitt, u wrote kind of hard to understand;_; so i made my own.

Comment: Please create and post a [mcve]

Comment: If i follow the MadProgrammer, the jlabel wont change the border, im using a not dynamic Jlabel, but instead a netbeans pre-created jlabel.

Comment: `"Complete Version of Code:"` -- ?? you've posted nothing that can be copied and pasted into an IDE, and then compiled and run. Your code has no class structure, no imports, no main method....

Comment: I hope u can run the code now.

Comment: Your Aplicacao class is missing its class declaration, its surrounding curly braces and possibly some variables.

Comment: .... plus the `initComponents()` method.....

Comment: See also the recommendation cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43902419/230513).

Comment: I took a more exhaustive look and seems that was the problem thanks, trashgod.

Comment: The answer can be found here[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43902419/230513).